# Setting Image ROI to a shape other an rectangle in EMGU CV...?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am working on a face detection and recognition software...i succeeded in detecting the faces and recognizing them using EigenObjectRecognizer...But sometimes its giving wrong results...So i would set the roi of the faces using HaarCascade object to an ellipse so that i should be able to nullify the effect of the background...

ellipse = new Ellipse(new PointF(face.rect.X + (face.rect.Width / 2), face.rect.Y + (face.rect.Height / 2)), new SizeF(face.rect.Width - 5, face.rect.Height - 25), 0);
ImageFrame.Draw(ellipse, new Bgr(Color.Green), 2);

Now it can draw an ellipse around the face...But how to set the face's roi to this ellipse...

Please help me with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but you can't actually set the ROI of the image to an ellipse, it's very complicated and slow to do this.

Well its not slow to do it parse but every time you access the image data it will be force to go through several for loops to find the correct position and conditions to make sure it does not stray. The detrimental effect to performance means it's not been implemented. You could always edit the source and set it up if you wanted.

Alternatively the best method you will have is to create a blank image of the ROI and copy the data of the face contained within the ellipse across using a couple of for loops byte by byte. You could also use the conditional copy to only copy skin coloured texture.

If you need a little help on this let me know. But eventually you will end up with a image of the face with a black background. Now since all faces will have a black background you can eliminate it's effect.

Hope this helps,

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using mask and bitwise And

Assume img is Image

Create mask:

```
Image<Gray, byte> mask = new Image<Gray, byte>(img.Width, img.Height);
```

Invoke a shape you want, for example ellipse

```
CvInvoke.Ellipse(mask,new Point(5,5),new Size(10,20),0,0,360, new MCvScalar(255,255,255),-1,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LineType.AntiAlias, 0); // -1 fill ellipse
```

Destination:

```
Image<Gray, byte> dest = new Image<Gray, byte>(img.Width, img.Height);
```

Bitwise And

```
dest = img.And(img, mask);
dest.Save("C:/myshape.jpg")
```